# fix cost and variable cost calculations

Tags: microeconomics, fixed-effects

[image]

Can someone explain why? I do not particularly understand. The average variable cost is $5, and I need the variable cost to calculate the fixed cost

Answer (score 1):

If $C(Q) = C_v(Q) + F$ is the cost function where $C_v(Q)$ is the variable cost and $F$ is the fixed cost, then

1. $AC(Q) = \frac{C_v(Q) + F}{Q}$
2. $AVC(Q) = \frac{C_v(Q)}{Q}$

You're given $AC(Q) = 11$, $AVC(Q) = 5$ and $Q = 100$. Can you plug in the values in the above definitions and continue?

Click on the spoiler for verification:

> $F = \\\$600$

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this spoiler tool!

Comment: @VARulle It exists but I am sure the temptation to reveal the spoiler makes it useless anyways haha. I have mostly seen it being used by the [puzzlers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).